# Disable SharePoint OOB button based on value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-jsom

I have a SharePoint "Save" button in the NewForm.aspx, which I am trying to disable through jQuery.
The button is shown as below in F12:

```
<input name="ctl00$ctl30$g_3bef9488_b9f0_405d_b989_cdfc35172f0d$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" id="ctl00_ctl30_g_3bef9488_b9f0_405d_b989_cdfc35172f0d_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem" accesskey="O" onclick="if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl30$g_3bef9488_b9f0_405d_b989_cdfc35172f0d$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" type="button" value="Save" target="_self">
```

Is it possible to disable the button in Jquery by checking its value. I mean, if the value is shown as "Save", then disable the button?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get the element whose value attribute ends with 'Save' and disable it.

```
$("input[value$='Save']").attr('disabled',true);
```